# In Dynamics CRM 2011 is there a way to highlight a row in a View?

Tags: gridview, view, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am searchig for a way to highlight a row in a View. I see that edition in views are really limited practically you can edit the query and columns to show.

However if I am able to show at least an icon inside the row in a certain column that would be enough.

Other way would be check if there is a tag in the XML source of the view that allows me mark (anymark) a row. As sample below the XML source of "All Quotes" view.

```xml
<grid name="resultset" object="1084" jump="name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1">
  <row name="result" id="quoteid">
    <cell name="name" width="300" />
    <cell name="statecode" width="100" />
    <cell name="totalamount" width="100" />
    <cell name="customerid" width="150" />
    <cell name="quotecustomeridcontactcontactid.emailaddress1" width="150" disableSorting="1" />
    <cell name="createdon" width="150" />
  </row>
</grid>
```

Thanks in advance

**Other Details**

I need this for both CRM's online and on premises.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CRM for Outlook you could use conditional formatting: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fJxWzp-qbo 

Otherwise try this: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/gayanperera/archive/2010/06/30/how-to-change-the-grid-icons-dynamically.aspx

It is unsupported and I have not tried it, but it looks like it will work.

Comment: +1 for Outlook comment, but I don't believe that the unsupported change is viable in CRM 2011. It certainly won't work in CRM Online (accepting that @MarcoMedrano hasn't specified CRM Online!)

Comment: @GregOwens it does not work with CRM Online as the application files are modified, which is not possible in this case

Comment: @ccellar Yup - just what I said ;)

Comment: + 1 Seems there is not a supported way even in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you add JScript to the view you can edit the view dynamically with an inline style sheet. 
The only way I know of to get JScript in a view is to add a button to the ribbon.

Please post if you find a solution to this problem.

Comment: It sounds weird but would be an alternative, hope have access to components outside ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Updating CRM styles or scripts are unsupported. I would recommend to show a view column attribute with desired value instead of trying to show a color or icon.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to develop a custom view in `silverlight` or in `asp.net`, if possible.
There you can format your custom view according to your requirement and this will supported way.

Comment: I did not see a way to replace the standard views by a custom view. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you can disable your existing view and should be able to show your custom view over sitemap or create a custom navigation for that.